# Can I change an element's key on a duplicated webform?

Tags: webforms

I was able to duplicate one of my forms and give its own unique machine-readable key. My concern is that the keys of its elements are the same as the keys on the original form.

I'm not given an option to edit the machine-readable key of an element on a duplicated form. Is there any harm in leaving that alone?

Would a unique machine-readable form key suffice?

Comment: Have you simply tried it out yourself? Did any problem occur?

Comment: Uniqueness per form is sufficient.